# Does the nucleophilic substitution in an acid chloride always proceed through a tetrahedral intermediate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

I am a beginner in organic chemistry and would like to ask for the mechanism for the nucleophilic substitution of carbonyl groups from acid chloride - especially regarding the tetrahedral intermediate? From the internet, what I got is:

- From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_carbonyl_addition_compound), tetrahedral intermediate exists.
- From [Clayden Organic chemistry (2nd edition)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FU9r.jpg), the mechanism of this reaction consists of the formation of the tetrahedral intermediate.

But I also found Schotten-Baumann synthesis of amides:

- [This website](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/schotten-baumann-reaction.shtm): it seems for the first step, nucleophilic attack of the nitrogen of amine directly results in the loss of the leaving group i.e. no tetrahedral intermediate.
- But it seems to me that only for this mechanism, that H+ can be produced (I can't draw a mechanism in which both tetrahedral intermediate and H+ are formed), and this HCl is transited to an aqueous phase and neutralized by NaOH, rendering this biphasic condition useful that 2nd eq. of amine need not be used.

What is the true mechanism for this reaction and **why**?

Comment: It always proceeds through the tetrahedral intermediate for carbonyls. The page you linked just shows this in one step as a shorthand. Do you see the arrow circling around the carbonyl oxygen? That means that a tetrahedral intermediate is formed then collapsed. The two steps are not shown explicitly but they are there.

Comment: Oh sorry I overlooked the circle on the around the oxygen, thanks for reminding

Comment: If you got the answer to your question, feel free to self-answer!